# Postgres initdb with custom timezone directory

Tags: postgresql, configuration, timezone

How can I run Postgres `initdb` with a custom timezone folder?

I've tried to use the `-L` flag and `PGSHAREDIR` env var to control where initdb searches for Postgres share data. However, those options don't seem to control how Postgres finds the timezone folder.

```
# CUSTOM_PG is a directory containing a complete, extracted
# installation of Postgres.
CUSTOM_PG=/my-custom-pg

PGSHAREDIR="$CUSTOM_PG/share/postgresql" \
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUSTOM_PG/lib"
$CUSTOM_PG/bin/initdb \
    --pgdata /tmp/my-data \
    --username=joe \
    --debug \
    -L "$CUSTOM_PG/share/postgresql"
```

Full context: I'm running Postgres with Bazel and I'd like to manage all of Postgres's dependencies with Bazel. The Postgres install, taken from Homebrew, searches for timezone data in /opt/homebrew/share/postgresql/timezone (which is outside Bazel's control), and I can't figure out how to override the timezone directory to the one managed by Bazel.

Here's the relevant logs from the initdb invocation above:

```
creating directory /tmp/my-data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting default time zone ... America/Los_Angeles
creating configuration files ... ok 
running bootstrap script ... 2021-11-23 01:56:52.567
[18352] LOG:  could not open directory "/opt/homebrew/share/postgresql/timezone": No such file or directory
INFO    pginit/cluster.go:478   [postgres] invalid value for parameter "log_timezone": "UTC"
[18352] LOG:  could not open directory "/opt/homebrew/share/postgresql/timezone": No such file or directory
[18352] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC"
[18352] FATAL:  configuration file "/var/folders/sb/f9x1r1p13/T/test-cluster-3607517384/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

It looks like initdb starts a Postgres process (with PID 18352) after creating a default config file. The started process doesn't seem to use PGSHAREDATA to locate the the timezone folder.

Related resources:

- [pgsql-bugs #4344 initdb -L timezone directory](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/13406.1218125046%40sss.pgh.pa.us): Bug from 2008 about setting a custom location for the timezone folder. Tom Lane mentions that `-L` is probably the wrong method and hints that `PGSHAREDIR` might work. Peter Eisentraut confirms that `-L` exists only for legacy reasons. This is the same question I've asked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify that during `initdb`. The location of the time zone files is compiled into PostgreSQL, and you can only change it when you configure and build PostgreSQL.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-procedure.html#CONFIGURE-OPTIONS-BUILD-PROCESS):

> `--with-system-tzdata=DIRECTORY`
>
> PostgreSQL includes its own time zone database, which it requires for date and time operations. This time zone database is in fact compatible with the IANA time zone database provided by many operating systems such as FreeBSD, Linux, and Solaris, so it would be redundant to install it again. When this option is used, the system-supplied time zone database in `DIRECTORY` is used instead of the one included in the PostgreSQL source distribution. `DIRECTORY` must be specified as an absolute path. `/usr/share/zoneinfo` is a likely directory on some operating systems. Note that the installation routine will not detect mismatching or erroneous time zone data. If you use this option, you are advised to run the regression tests to verify that the time zone data you have pointed to works correctly with PostgreSQL.

You can check how your PostgreSQL was built with

```bash
pg_config --configure
```

If that option was not used, PostgreSQL will use its own time zone database, located in the `SHAREDIR`, which you can find with

```bash
pg_config --sharedir
```

The `-L` option of `initdb` specifies where `initdb` will look for `postgres.bki`, `pg_hba.conf.sample`, `pg_ident.conf.sample`, `postgresql.conf.sample`, `snowball_create.sql`, `information_schema.sql`, `sql_features.txt`, `system_constraints.sql`, `system_functions.sql` and `system_views.sql`.

You misread the pgsql-bugs thread: there is no way to specify the location of the share directory during `initdb`. That is also hard-wired.

Comment: Thank you! Sounds like what I want is a relocatable build: https://begriffs.com/posts/2016-05-21-relocatable-postgresql.html

Comment: Perhaps. First, decide if you want to use the system tzdata or the one that comes with PostgreSQL. Don't you install PostgreSQL in a fixed location?

Comment: The use-case is spinning up ephemeral Postgres databases for each "unit" test. If I can isolate Postgres within my build system (bazel) and not rely on an external system directories, it's easier to onboard new devs and tests are reproducible across machines.